# MasterPage Data Bind to GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a Master Page with nested pages in ASP.NET. Fairly simply I want to databind some hyperlinks to a gridview for the master page. This however is throwing a null reference exception when I try to set the DataSource.

1. I tested the code on a separate page and it works as expected.
2. When debugging I can see the Page_Load Sub hit twice, I don't know if this is the cause
3. I have one nested page being loaded, this is a blank page at the moment

**EXCEPTION**

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[image]

**MASTERPAGE CODE BEHIND**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Using model = New AccessDataModelDataContext
            Dim result = From x In model.SiteLinks
                         Where x.IsActive
                         Select x

            SiteLinks.DataSource = result
            SiteLinks.DataBind()
        End Using
    End If

End Sub
```

**MASTERPAGE ASPX CODE**

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="Access.Manager.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="~/Styles/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Site.Master
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <div class="navigation">
            Site Links
            <asp:GridView ID="SiteLinks" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
            </div>

        <div class="content">Site Content</div>


        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that codebehind for your masterpage, or a page that uses your masterpage?

Comment: That's the codebehind the masterpage. I will update for clarification.

Comment: Add a breakpoint to verify that `result` is not null.  The way I typically do it is to provide a minimum of an empty result (not null).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, just checked it using a breakpoint and using `If result IsNot Nothing Then` but its still a problem...

Comment: And does checking IsNot Nothing work?  Or you still getting exception?

Comment: Sorry completely missed adding that bit in... yes its still an issue. I think it cant reference the GridView control "SiteLinks" on the master page for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One glaring issue that I see, and could be your problem, is that your GridView exists inside of your content placeholder.  Generally, those placeholders are for pages to implement, not the masterpage itself.

Move the contents of the place holder out of it:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Site.Master
        <div class="navigation">
            Site Links
            <asp:GridView ID="SiteLinks" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        <div class="content">Site Content</div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! How could I miss that, of course you cant access the control if its in the place holder. Thanks!

Comment: You bet.  So, in essence, I believe what was happening is your page (that is using your master page) is overriding the contents of that placeholder, thus it couldn't find the gridview (because your page didn't define a gridview for the placeholder).

Answer (score 1):

We can bind data to  master page Gridview from content page like this,

```
GridView grid_data = this.Master.FindControl("show_zone_data") as GridView;

grid_data.DataSource = dt;
grid_data.DataBind();
```